# Set Cron Job Between Specific Times and Frequency

Tags: cron, scheduler, hangfire

For example I want to run job every 6 minutes between;

16:34  - 18:45

So it must be running on 16:34, 16:40, 16:46 etc. to 18:40.

When I write

```
34-45 16-18 * * *
```

It only works between 16:34-16:45 and 18:34-18:45. But I don't want this one.

Is it possible to make this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hm, where in your cron line is the "every 6 minutes" part?  Also, why would your cron go to `18:40`, wouldn't `18:42` be the last time you want it to run?  Let me know if I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Anyway though, not sure if it's possible in one cron line, but you could always do something like:

```
34/6 16 * * *
*/6 17 * * * 
0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42 18 * * *
```

Edit: Or, if you have control and are able to edit the file/executable your cron is running you could do:

```
*/6 16-18 * * * /path/to/myScript
```

And then at the very beginning of `myScript`:

```
if time < 16:34 or time > 18:45:
    exit # kill script
```

Comment: I'm using Hangfire as a scheduler. It waits for cron string. How can I pass more than one cron string to it? And I take this time values from user with time picker. So it must be worked dynamically.

Comment: @Gyepesto hm sorry I don't have experience with Hangfire or time picker, I was just assuming you were adding lines to your user's crontab or something (`crontab -e`).  Instead of passing more than one string to it, can you just make 3 separate calls with one string each? Perhaps if you edit your question with your actual code I'll be able to help.